# How to unpack unsigned char byte array from UDP in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, udp, byte

I'm creating a UDP sender/receiver application in C++. I am successfully packing and sending the packet over UDP, and successfully receiving the same packet over UDP however the problem comes when I try to unpack the packet into a byte array. I receive the byte array of size 51 with no issues. I then convert it to a `std::vector<unsigned char>` and try to create new vectors based on the variable sizes in the packet structure.

The packet structure is this and is 51 bytes long:

```
uint16 data1;
double data2;
double data3;
double data4;
double data5;
double data6;
double data7;
uint8 data8;
```

I create my buffer inside a function called receiveArray that returns a `std::vector<unsigned char>`:

```
int BUFFSIZE = 51;
unsigned char buf[BUFFSIZE];
```

I receive the packet without errors. I then create a vector based on `buf` with the following code and return the vector:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> output(buf, buf + BUFFSIZE);
return output;
```

I call the `receiveArray` function and put it into a vector called `buf` which also displays the correct vector size of 51.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buf = receiver.receiveArray();
```

I then try to split up the vector by index and use memcpy to convert the vectors into the correct values.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data1Vector(buf.begin(), buf.begin()+1);
std::vector<unsigned char> data2Vector(buf.begin()+2, buf.begin()+9);
std::vector<unsigned char> data3Vector(buf.begin()+10, buf.begin()+17);
double data1, data2, data3;
memcpy(&data1, &data1Vector, sizeof(uint16_t));
memcpy(&data2, &data2Vector, sizeof(double));
memcpy(&data3, &data3Vector, sizeof(double));
```

Obviously this doesn't work and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have a very similar piece of code written in python which decodes the packet correctly, so I don't think it's my packet structure or packing. It's my implementation. I don't use any serialisation protocols either.

I'm quite new to C++ and have probably made some horrible mistakes.Thanks for your help, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: You're `memcpy`ing the vectors internal structure, not the data it contains.

Comment: @tkausl do I need to do &data1Vector.data()?

Comment: `int BUFFSIZE = 51;unsigned char buf[BUFFSIZE];` missing `const`, else you use VLA extension which is not valid C++.

Comment: BTW, if you already have a buffer, you don't need to use intermediate `std::vector` to do `memcpy`.

Comment: BTW, with `memcpy`, you don't handle endianess. And not sure that `double` has guarantied binary representation.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42 I converted to vector because I wasn't sure how to split the buffer array into the corresponding bytes.

Comment: There are few mistakes: `uint16_t data1; double data2, data3;`

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned char> data1Vector(buf.begin(), buf.begin()+1);
std::vector<unsigned char> data2Vector(buf.begin()+1, buf.begin()+9);
std::vector<unsigned char> data3Vector(buf.begin()+9, buf.begin()+17);`

Comment: Different architectures represent the binary values differently. Are you transmitting between different architectures?

Comment: Your offsets seem wrong. You have one byte for your `16bit` value and a single byte gap between all your vectors.

Comment: @Oliv thank you. I've made the changes but it's still not showing the correct information. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my method?

Comment: @Galik I'm sending and receiving on the same socket on the same computer so it shouldn't be an issue with architecture.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It seems like it was my byte offsets were incorrect, it all seems to be working with the correct offsets. 

Also thank you to @Oliv for pointing out that variable type bug.

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned char> data1Vector(buf.begin(), buf.begin()+2); std::vector<unsigned char> data2Vector(buf.begin()+2, buf.begin()+10); std::vector<unsigned char> data3Vector(buf.begin()+10, buf.begin()+18);`

Comment: For reference and helping others above was the main issue. Thanks all.